# Connected components and limited sets

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness, path-connected

$X \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a limited subset. Prove that $\mathbb{R}^{n} - X$ has exactly one ilimited connected component, for $n > 1$.

I tried to show that if $\mathbb{R}^{n} - X$ has more than one ilimited connected component, then $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ isn't limited, but i don't even know how to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not true in general: take $n=1$ and $X = \{0\}$. Any additional condition on $n$?

Comment: Also not true when $n=0$ :)

Comment: @Gibbs, sorry! n must be greater than 1.

Comment: Did you find at least one unbounded connected component in the first place?

Comment: @Gibbs no, how could this help to find a solution?

Comment: @ganom51 what's a bounded set according to your definitions?